# Using sinon js library to mock an existing function used by the test code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am new to the js modern programming and testing so I might use the incorrect terms. I am using React and the ES6 syntax and using jest and sinon for my tests.

I want to mock/stub/replace an existing function in my code so that it's not called and returns a predetermined result.

I'll add here the code to test

```js
import get_products from './products';

function fetchProducts() {

some_code()

get_products()

some_more_code()

}
```

And in my test

```js
import 'fetchProducts' from '../main';

test('fetchProducts', () => {

fetchProducts();

})
```

What I'm trying to do is mock the get_products() function so it is not actually called, but rather returns a predetermined result when testing the fetchProducts() function.
I looked at sinon help for days but cannot figure out.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested that but should work as expected.

```
before(function() {
    sinon.stub(get_products).yields(null, JSON.stringify({ hello: 'World!' }));
});

it('get_products should be called', function() {
    fetchProducts();
    get_products.called.should.be.equal(true);
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Freshman, thanks for answering, but how does your code knows about get_products? I get ReferenceError if I use it like this

Comment: if I import it like import get_products from '../products' I get: TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function